# How to solve google chrome "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" issue in windows 10 when server is running on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, flask, vpn, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to run this [project](https://github.com/intuinno/conceptvector) on Ubuntu 18.04 server. I am running both server and client on this machine. Then from windows 10 with port 9000 I am getting access to client in my chrome browser at http://localhost:8000/#/

The browser loads the project but the problem is I can't log into the website with trusted account and some other data do not get loaded . When I see browser console I see an error message saying:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

This is the server setting:
[image]

This is the client setting and putty setting to connect to client.
[image]

**VPN has been used to connect to server via PuTTY**.

The error message in browser:
[image]

Could anyone shed some light on this issue? Is it related to windows 10 or VPN or some other issues? I followed some steps from here https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-reset/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the Flask development environment uses 127.0.0.1 (localhost), which restricts access to processes on the same host (except for VMs/containers, which aren't a factor here).

To access Flask from outside of localhost (e.g., from your Windows 10 machine), use the IP address 0.0.0.0. (You can pass it to `run()`, or via a command line option of the `flask` command.

However, do note the warnings about (not) using the development environment for production use.

Comment: IP address 0.0.0.0 has already been used here. https://github.com/intuinno/conceptvector/blob/master/server/app.py

Comment: Your logs shows 127.0.0.1 in use. How are you launching the app? If you're using the `flask` command, it's doing the `run()` for you. `flask --help` will point you in the right direction.

Comment: The client is also hosted on Ubuntu server. Windows 10 (port 8000) is just listening to remote host client (port 9000)